# What is Smalltalk way to store/reuse changes to others code?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I started to tweak Squeak classes to make them perform what is the best behaviour for me. In particular I added a message: `MCGitRepository>>gitCommandWithOutput` and I modified another: `MCRemoteGitRepository>>basicStoreVersion`.

I saved the image. I will have my changes working next time I boot Squeak. ok.

Now, suppose I want to save my changes and load them tomorrow in a new Squeak image. Or move them to another computer.

I have my own `myClass` to add methods to existing classes but, in this case, I need also to change an existing message,
`MCRemoteGitRepository>>basicStoreVersion`.

What is the best practice in Smalltalk for this situation ?

P.S. `Metacello` & `Metacello-git` which I am tweaking, live in GitHub. Please don't focus this fact. Suppose I want to change `Regex-Core` or something else which comes from Squeaksource, Squeakmap or else. So, we can't assume I am modifying something coming from Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either maintain your overrides/extensions to the base image (and packages from other sources) in changeset(s) or package(s).  Changesets are the simplest approach but they can get somewhat cumbersome to maintain as they evolve over time.  For that reason, I would recommend using packages.

To make a method (whether one you added or a method override) part of one of your own packages, just change the category of the method using the Browser.  For example, to change the package that `MCRemoteGitRepository>>basicStoreVersion` belongs to:

- navigate to the class and highlight the method name in the browser (the right-most pane at the top of the browser window)
- right click to get the context menu
- select `more...`
- then select `change category...`
- select `new...` then click `Choose`
- type in your package name prefixed with an asterisk (i.e. for
  MyPackage you would type *MyPackage)
  then click `Accept`

Before discarding your working image, be sure to save your package.  Then all you need to do is load your package(s) into a fresh image to incorporate your changes.

Comment: I see, thank you blihp. Now I am thinking: [1] What will happen if I update the package Metagello-Git? There will be two messages called `basicStoreVersion` under the same object. [2] Most importantly, is there a nice way I can see all messages defined by MyPackage, including the ones living in the *MyPackage protocol.

Comment: [1] Think of the resulting image as disposable: your source of truth is a composition of the image, repo packages and your packages.  So rather than updating packages in an existing image, you would build a new one from the most recent image, lastest packages in the repos and then install your package(s) as an overlay. [2] If you browse your package in the Monticello browser, all of your extensions and overrides in that package will be listed under the *Extensions category.

Comment: [1] got it ! [2] found 30 min ago, same as you said:) Thank you again.